# Monitoring MySQL SELECT/WRITE/UPDATE/SLOW queries in Nagios

Tags: mysql, monitoring, nagios

There's ways to get performance graphs with several monitoring software packages out there such as ZenOSS. There's a plugin available that will graph MySQL based SELECT/WRITE/SLOW queries in a nice rrd style graph.

I'm curious if there is a way to also get similar graphs available in Nagios 3.0? I know Nagios has tools like pnp and can integrate rrd, but is there something readily available that can plugin to monitor those MySQL specifics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.monitoringexchange.org/inventory/Check-Plugins/Database/MySQL/check_mysql_perf.  It might suite your needs.  You'll still need to use something like perfmon if you want to graph it.

Answer (score 1):

I use PNP as a quick-and-dirty means of producing graphs through Nagios.

Then I would look at a URL like [this](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/MySQL).